# How to troubleshoot ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with basic Jquery HTTPrequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a very basic HTTP request to a site hosted on a Java HTTP Server. However no matter what I try I get the following error. Can anyone help me understand what it is and how I can resolve it? I don't believe its due to timeout as the request is pinging relatively quickly.

**The error i receive:**

```
GET http://sabernet.ddns.net:8080/api/devices/9be0a1cf-d7d9-48f4-9122-26a8e295cae3/schedules (request.js:15)
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

**My sample JS code:**

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET','http://sabernet.ddns.net:8080/api/devices/9be0a1cf-d7d9-48f4-9122-26a8e295cae3/schedules');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
request.send();
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you open to jQuery answers ?

Comment: Yessir any solution helps!

Comment: If origin or port is different than page you make request from you need to enable CORS on remote server. Setting Access Control headers in request is useless, they must be set in the response. If you don't control the remote use a proxy on server you control or a third party service

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Do you know what headers need to be set via the response?

Comment: If you put the proxy on the same domain as the webpage you don't need to send any CORS headers. Otherwise it is more complex and you will need to check out the CORS documentation.